# Crashing During Iteration Of NSArray With Swift On iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am not quite sure why this is not working, but I have an array populated with various data. I have tested the amount of rows in the array by using this:

```
println("Total Count: " + "\(testArray.count)")
```

This returns 29 items. I have also verified that each key / value pair is filled by looking at the output from:

```
for result : AnyObject in testArray
{
    println(\"(result)")
}
```

However when I try and get it to print the output of any given value, only the first one prints and the app crashes on the second loop. I don't get an error in the console but I get the message:

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

in the code. Here is the full code block:

```
for result : AnyObject in testArray
{
    var testVariable = result.valueForKey("testColumn") as NSObject
    println(testVariable)
}
```

The app crashes on the second loop on the "var testVariable" line. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the console output from the first two rows of data from my array:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0xd16e940> (entity: Shows; id: 0xd16fb40 <x-coredata://2DADFB50-FB10-4345-9252-1AFFF3598BBD/Shows/p22> ; data: {
   showId = 2492;
   showImageFilePath = "/Users/Andy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2944D5A5-1D0A-4C23-BA74-54FEA1C2BB2E/data/Containers/Data/Application/8F6B6E36-87EA-45F8-94A7-F3E5278B8604/Documents\\ShowImages\\2492-All Shook Up.jp";
   showIsCurrent = 1;
   showIsWatched = 0;
   showName = "All Shook Up";
   showUrl = "http://lv.houseseats.com/member/tickets/view/?showid=2492";
})

<NSManagedObject: 0xd16ecf0> (entity: Shows; id: 0xd16fb50 <x-coredata://2DADFB50-FB10-4345-9252-1AFFF3598BBD/Shows/p50> ; data: <fault>)

<NSManagedObject: 0xd16eec0> (entity: Shows; id: 0xd16fb60 <x-coredata://2DADFB50-FB10-4345-9252-1AFFF3598BBD/Shows/p24> ; data: {
   showId = 2719;
   showImageFilePath = "/Users/Andy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2944D5A5-1D0A-4C23-BA74-54FEA1C2BB2E/data/Containers/Data/Application/8F6B6E36-87EA-45F8-94A7-F3E5278B8604/Documents\\ShowImages\\2719-Bonkerz Comedy ";
   showIsCurrent = 1;
   showIsWatched = 0;
   showName = "Bonkerz Comedy Club Presents: Rio Hillman";
   showUrl = "http://lv.houseseats.com/member/tickets/view/?showid=2719";
})
```

Also, this is my first time trying to code for iOS as well as posting on Stack Overflow, so please bear with me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the array?

Comment: Sure. I updated my original post. Actually, on the second NSManagedObject it lists <fault> instead of any values. What does this mean exactly? Is there an SQLite viewer for Xcode so I can easily visualize all the data I have in the database? This array comes from using store data using CoreData.

Comment: Please take the time to format your question correctly (especially the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log output, it seems you are using `NSManagedObject`. Why use `AnyObject`? Maybe it does  not understand `valueForKey`. Try casting your array elements as what they are, `NSManagedObject`s.

Also, if the property is a string, cast it as String, not something else.